# Regular expression to not to split if it's inside a particular pattern

Tags: java, regex

I have a custom string which is a streamed version of multiple item. Item can be Integer, String and List of String where each item 
represented by **I,S,L** respectively.

```
For eg: String d = "I:123;S:345;L:{S:45;S:67;S:789};I:23";
```

I am trying to write a single regular expression which could split this string and should produce  4 items

```
1. I:123,  2. S:345, 3.L:{s:45;s:67;s:789}; ,4:I:23
```

If I just split based on ;then it will split items List of also that should not happen.Then I tried to write some complex regular expression but nothing worked.

Could some one please give some pointer?

Comment: Why last `I:23` shouldn't be a separate item?

Comment: @anubhava corrected it. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this lookahead based regex for splitting:

```
String[] arr = str.split(";(?![^{}]*})");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/At2bZU/1)

**Details:**

- `;`: Match literal `;`
- `(?![^{}]*})`: Negative lookahead to make sure we don'r have a `}` after non `{` and `}` characters

Comment: Thanks man. It really worked. I will definitely consider buying your book ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the lazy quantifiers:

```
(.+?);(.+?);(.*)
```

Links:

- https://regex101.com/r/3nrRxP/1
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: It was before the comment of @anubhava